# Gitlab yml cannot retreive password when create the new branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

I create the gitlab ci yml as below:

```
before_script:  
  - export GITLAB_PACKAGE_REGISTRY_USERNAME="DeployUser"
  - export GITLAB_PACKAGE_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$DeployPassword
  - dotnet restore ${PROJECT} --packages ./.nuget/ --verbosity quiet

Build and Test:
  stage: build and test
  script:
    - dotnet build ${PROJECT} --no-restore -c Release --verbosity quiet -o out
    Release
  when: always
  only:
    - develop
    - /^Production/[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)+$/
```

and the nuget.config as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="gitlab" value="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567/packages/nuget/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
     <gitlab>
         <add key="Username" value="%GITLAB_PACKAGE_REGISTRY_USERNAME%" />
         <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%GITLAB_PACKAGE_REGISTRY_PASSWORD%" />
     </gitlab>
 </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

When I push source code to gitlab into develop branch, it's all green and sucess, but when I create the new branch name Production/1.0  from develop
It throw below error

> $ export GITLAB_PACKAGE_REGISTRY_USERNAME="DeployUser" $ export
> GITLAB_PACKAGE_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$DeployPassword $ dotnet restore
> ${PROJECT} --packages ./.nuget/ --verbosity quiet
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.408/NuGet.targets(565,5): error : Value
> cannot be null or empty string. (Parameter 'password')
> [/builds/codefactory/myproject.csproj]

can I know the problem inside ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are configured by your administrator to be protected by default.

https://gitlab.ipaidthat.io/help/ci/variables/index#protect-a-cicd-variable

Can you ensure your variable is not protected, or your branch is a protected branche?